# How to show some labels only at certain scales?

Tags: qgis, labeling, scale

I am using QGIS 2.14 and I want to set my contour line lables so that my minor labels (every half a metre) are only shown at a scale under 1:1000, while having all my major (every metre) labels always showing. I assume you can do this in the expression builder - but I am not sure where to find the 'Maximum' function name.

So far I have:

```
Case
When "Elevation" Like '%.5' THEN ????
When "Elevation Like '%.0' THEN ???
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rule based labelling.  Can't be 100% sure as I'm on 2.16 but that you can set what scale the labels are shown and I believe that it is available in 2.14 but if you check out this screenshot for 2.12 it is available then: [Rule-based labeling and the Data defined placement options are not working together (QGIS 2.12, 2.14)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/171999/73835)

**EDIT: Simplified method**

OK having a quick play on 2.16 under 'rendering' in the layer properties you have scale based visibility.  Using the data defined option you can set a CASE/WHEN statement on the  maximum scale value like:

```
CASE WHEN "Elevation" LIKE '%.5' THEN 1000
END
```

This will only show the 0.5 labels with scales under 1000. Again this is on 2.16

Comment: That worked for me, thanks!

Is it not possible to do using the " CASE WHEN" method?